# Redirect entire request to new domain, without post-pending ANY content after the .com of the original request

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have google'd for at least 3 hours and tried all the examples on stack overflow and other forums.
Does anyone know how to use .htaccess (either redirect or rewrite) to be able to redirect all traffic from one domain to another without passing anything after the .com?

I have an old domain:

```
http://www.olddomain.com
```

I want to redirect ALL requests to that domain to a specific URL

```
http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/
```

I have tried quite a few types of redirects and rewrite rules in .htaccess, but if I make a request like:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/some/directory/
```

the redirect always comes to the new domain like:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/some/directory/
```

The redirect is post pending the URI onto the redirect.

I have tried adding ? at the end of the new URL and that does not help.

Here are some of my redirects. (Domain names changed to protect the innocent)

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/? [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule /?$ http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/? [R=301,L]
```

I tried the Redirect command as well...

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/?
```

None of these seems to remove the /some/directory/ and just keep redirecting to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/some/directory/
```

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/?
```

But if you would rather use mod_rewrite, it looks like you were pretty close with your rules, it just needs to have the regular expression match *anything*:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/new/directory/? [R=301,L]
```

There's a caveat that if both of these domains are actually hosted on the same server, the same document root, and you're going to be putting this in an htaccess file, then you'll need to add an additional check above the `RewriteRule` for the host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain.com$ [NC]
```